# Fast loading and processing of dictionaries with 90 million elements

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary

I have a table of the form:

```
source ||| target ||| s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 ||| ||| c1 c2 .
```

There are two files of this form, with 90 million and 50 million rows respectively. I want to process them to generate a new file. But, as I am making mistakes each time, it is too time-taking to load the files and generate dicts out of it. And if I use marshal to dump and load them each time, it still takes quite a bit of time. Is there a faster way? Code attached for both cases.

```
htEnPT = defaultdict(list)
for phrase in open(phraseTable,'r'):
    parts = phrase.split(' ||| ')
    sourcePhrase = removePunctuations(parts[0])
    htEnPT[sourcePhrase].append(removePunctuations(parts[1]),parts[2],parts[3])
```

This loads the dict each time and takes a long long time.

And if I do this after doing the above,

```
marshal.dump(dict(PhraseTable),open(sys.argv[4],'wb'))
```

Then, doing this:

```
marshal.load(open(sys.argv[1],'rb'))
```

still takes a really long time.

So, is there a faster way of dealing with such large files when prototyping? 
Thanks.

Comment: `itertools.islice(open(phraseTable), 100)` will generate only the first 100 lines from the file

Comment: What does "generate a new file" entail? Can you do it incrementally as you read the separate files as iterators, or do you really need to have all 140 million records accessible at once?

Comment: does your files are text files???

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subset of rows of the file for testing.